# html5 direct file uploads security risk?

Tags: html, security, file-upload

I'm using html5 canvas based image uploads with base64 encoding (default). server-side: when a request is posted base64 headers are removed and base64_decode function (eval php function is not used at all) is applied and saved as jpg directly onto filesystem.

Since i'm saving uploaded file as an exact copy of what is uploaded. if a user uploads a malicious php/js file masqueraded as jpg and a visitor views that bad jpg is this a security risk? if yes I'll process uploaded file with gd. after gd-processed i assume those will be gone.

Comment: for me or user but that does not change the outcome since solution is processing all uploads with gd.

Answer (score 0):

> Since i'm saving uploaded file as an exact copy of what is uploaded.

Then you have all the problems you get when dealing with any kind of file upload. There is nothing specific to HTML 5 here.

> if a user uploads a malicious php/js file masqueraded as jpg and a visitor views that bad jpg is this a security risk?

Assuming that you deliver it over HTTP with an `image/jpeg` content-type — no.

However, there have been problems in the past with buffer overflow based vulnerabilities in image libraries, so it is theoretically possible (albeit unlikely) that a specially crafted JPEG could exploit a security vulnerability in an end viewer's system.

Comment: "Assuming that you deliver it over HTTP with an image/jpeg content-type — no." i don't think answer is a straight no that's why asked.

Comment: @opteronn — Given that scenario and that assumption, the answer *is* a straight "no".

Comment: "Then you have all the problems you get when dealing with any kind of file upload. There is nothing specific to HTML 5 here." html5 because of default usage of base64 encoding in toDataURL() method.

Comment: @opteronn — You have to decode the data from base64 back to a binary. Then you have a file and everything is the same as for any other file upload.

Comment: a scenario might be putting a specially crafted gif file as valid jpg.

Comment: @opteronn — That's a different scenario, and one that is covered in the last paragraph of the answer.